# Pandas on GAE flexible Won't Subset DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, google-app-engine

Trying to subset a df by name inside a for loop that progresses through a list of names:

```
names = ['Name','Name','Name']
>>> type(names[0])
<type 'str'>
```

df has a 'Name' column that is an object type containing strings, and when run locally, expressions like

```
for i in names:
    csum = time_data.ix[:,(time_data['Name'].values==i)]
```

or

```
csum = time_data.loc[time_data['Name']==i]
```

work just fine.  However, once the app is deployed to GAE flexible, pandas throws

```
KeyError: False
```

for the first expression and

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

for the second. This is Pandas version 0.22 and python 2.7.14.  Can anybody tell me what's going on and how to fix it?!

df looks like:

```
>>> time_data.head()
    Date        Name       In AM       Out AM        In PM      Out PM  
0 2018-01-04  TESTY TEST  7:03:24 AM  12:06:24 PM  12:38:06 PM  5:34:30 PM   
1 2018-01-07  TESTY TEST  3:14:25 PM          NaN          NaN         NaN   

>>> time_data.dtypes
Date                 datetime64[ns]
Name                         object
In AM                        object
Out AM                       object
In PM                        object
Out PM                       object
dtype: object
>>> type(time_data.Name[0])
<type 'str'>
```

Full tracebacks:

```
/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py:816: 
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but 
in the future will perform elementwise comparison

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app response = 
self.full_dispatch_request() File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request rv = 
self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception 
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request rv = 
self.dispatch_request() File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request return 
self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) File 
"/home/vmagent/app/timecard_report/views.py", line 192, in preview mask = 
(time_data['Name']==i) File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 879, in wrapper res = na_op(values, 
other) File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", 
line 818, in na_op raise TypeError("invalid type comparison") TypeError: 
invalid type comparison

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app response = 
self.full_dispatch_request() File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request rv = 
self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception 
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request rv = 
self.dispatch_request() File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request return 
self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) File 
"/home/vmagent/app/timecard_report/views.py", line 192, in preview csum = 
time_data.ix[:,(time_data['Name'].values==i)] File 
"/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 121, 
in __getitem__ return self._getitem_tuple(key) File 
"/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 858, 
in _getitem_tuple return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup) File 
"/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 991, 
in _getitem_lowerdim section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i) File 
"/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1108, 
in _getitem_axis return self._get_label(key, axis=axis) File 
"/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 145, 
in _get_label return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis) File 
"/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2335, 
in xs return self[key] File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__ return 
self._getitem_column(key) File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column return 
self._get_item_cache(key) File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache values = 
self._data.get(item) File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3843, in get loc = 
self.items.get_loc(item) File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2527, in get_loc return 
self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key)) File 
"pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in 
pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 
139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc File 
"pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item File 
"pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: False
```

Comment: Catching the exceptions and logging out the `dtypes` and a few rows of the DataFrame would be helpful.

Comment: Sure thing, @Alex!

Comment: Does the list `names` only contain strings?

Comment: Yep.  Finally figured this out after a lot of trial and error. GAE has been chock full of errors like this....oy vey!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, GAE pandas will only accept:

```
csum = time_data.query('Name=='+ "'"+i+"'")
```

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This is super weird... a bug report would be great if this is not documented!

Comment: Hah. Thanks @Alex! Debugging this thing has been driving me crazy for the past week! Might be related to https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13129 ?